# Find a resource (.txt file) in war file which is deployed standalone or in ear

Tags: java, classloader, war

I have a war file is packaged in ear and deployed. Here is the structure:

```
EAR
-WAR
--input.txt
--META-INF
--WEB-INF
---classes
(and so on)
```

I am trying to read **input.txt** from one of the classes (say abc.xyz.Myclass) in WEB-INF/classes folder. Here is what I tried:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../../input.txt");
```

and

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../../input.txt");
```

I tried several paths like "../input.txt" or "/input.txt" or just "input.txt" by attaching a debugger. But every time I am getting NULL as return value (means it is not able to find the file).

What is the correct way to access that file in war irrespective of whether war is deployed standalone or it is packed in ear? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `input.txt` is outside of the classpaths, one of which is typically `WEB-INF/classes/`, and you cannot access resources that is located outside the classpath using classloaders.

Alternatively, if the code can access the `HttpServletRequest` object:

```
    request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/input.txt");
```

Of course there is other ways to obtain the `ServletContext` instance.

Comment: I can find my txt file inside in my .war file inside WEB-INF/classes/ but I couldn't read it it return NULL Pointer, any idea on how to specify the path?

Answer (score 5):

When using `getResource()`, the resource needs to be on the classpath. Therefore you need to put `input.txt` somewhere under the `classes` directory.

Comment: Isn't there any way to load a resource which is not on classpath?

Comment: Not with `getResource()`. Is there a reason why it can't be on the classpath?

Comment: No big reason. The war is already packaged and with the customer. I thought of making no change in existing war structure.

Comment: It'll be a lot cleaner and easier to just keep it on the classpath, than start creating weird hacks to access the file.