# java.io.FileNotFoundException when running on server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am using Java 8 with Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE.

I have the following code, that works when I run the `main` as a java application. However, when I deploy it to a Tomcat server, and a thread calls it, I get the following error:

**error**

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12 (No such file or directory)

**code**

```
private static String PATH_TO_P12_CERT = "src/main/resources/certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12";

private String sendIOSPushNotification(String device_token, String topics, String title, String message)
        throws Exception {
    ApnsServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = APNS.newService();
        serviceBuilder.withCert(PATH_TO_P12_CERT, CERT_PASSWORD)
                .withProductionDestination();
    ApnsService service = serviceBuilder.build();
    String payload = APNS.newPayload()
            .alertBody(message)
            .alertTitle(title)
            .sound("default")
            .customField("custom", "custom value").build();
    service.push(device_token, payload);

    return "iOS Push Notification: " + title + " " + message;
}
```

**Question**

How do I define the path to the `apns-prod-cert.p12`?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: If you run your code outside of an IDE there is no `/src/main/resources` Directory. Use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12")`

Comment: Then should I reference it by: `/certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12`?

Comment: In a typical WAR environment (which gets deployed to Tomcat), there aren't even _files_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a resource (.txt file) in war file which is deployed standalone or in ear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819735/find-a-resource-txt-file-in-war-file-which-is-deployed-standalone-or-in-ear)

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code outside of an IDE there is no `/src/main/resources` Directory. Use `serviceBuilder.withCert(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/certificates/apns-prod‌​-cert.p12"),CERT_PASSWORD)`

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. I don't think it's the most elegant, but I will use it for now Until something better comes up.

I moved the resource `apns-prod-cert.p12` to the same directory as the class (`NotificationServiceImpl`) that's making use of it. Then I do the following:

```
String certPath = NotificationServiceImpl.class.getResource("apns-prod-cert.p12").getPath();
```

This is not the best, because it means I have to package `apns-prod-cert.p12` with the java where I would normally want it under `resources`.

Comment: Yes that is not the best way.

Answer (score -2):

You should consider in your production environment you don't have the src folder. Instead, everything inside the resources folder is put to the classpath. Try:

```
private static String PATH_TO_P12_CERT = "classpath:certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12";
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. Not sure why someone has given you a down vote?

Comment: If it doesn't work try creating a file with PATH constant, and passing the file to your method.

Comment: Do you think that `new FileInputStream("classpath:certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12");` works? That is what internelly happends:https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/blob/master/src/main/java/com/notnoop/apns/ApnsServiceBuilder.java

Comment: where is the FileInputStream? I didn't see this in the code

Comment: See the provided link line 156

Comment: I do not think so, becaude FileInputStream expect a filename and `classpath:` isn't one

Comment: I am busy deploying this solution to my Tomcat server, will test, and let you know the results.

Comment: make sure the file is inside the classes folder, if not, check if there are exclusions while adding resource files to your project on your IDE or maven configuration file

Comment: On the server, I get: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12`.

Comment: you can try adding a slash before classpath:/certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12

Comment: Nope, on the server, I get:  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:/certificates/apns-prod-cert.p12`.

Comment: @Ademir Constantino, thank you for your help. I managed to get it working, although not the best solution. See my answer above.